# How to getIID from model in Android

Tags: android, list, arraylist

In my application I want use ChipView, from this Library : https://github.com/adroitandroid/ChipCloud
For fill chips item I write below code :

```
    private String tagString;
    private List<NewsDetailTag> tags = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
call.enqueue(new Callback<NewsDetailResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<NewsDetailResponse> call, Response<NewsDetailResponse> response) {
                if (response.body().getData() != null) {
                    // Chip
                    for (NewsDetailTag tag : tags) {
                        tagString = tag.getName();
                        chip_cloud.addChip(tagString);
                    }
                    chip_cloud.setChipListener(new ChipListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void chipSelected(int i) {
                            Toast.makeText(NewsDetailActivity.this, "" + i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void chipDeselected(int i) {
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<NewsDetailResponse> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
```

In my `NewsDetailTag` (model), has **Name** and **ID**.
With above codes I can `getName` and set in **chip**.
But I want when click on Chips item, show name's **ID** in `Toast`.

```
chip_cloud.setChipListener(new ChipListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void chipSelected(int i) {
                            Toast.makeText(NewsDetailActivity.this, "" + i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void chipDeselected(int i) {
                        }
                    });
```

Show **name's ID** from `NewsDetailTag` instead of **`i`** in `Toast`.

I want **getID** from `tag.getID()` and when click on Chips item, show name's **ID** (`getID`) in `Toast`

How can I it? Please help me guys, I really your helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Toast.makeText(NewsDetailActivity.this, "" + tags.get(i).getName() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

tags.get(i) : Return the object from the i position in the list

Comment: Thank you my dear friend. your answer is very help for me <3